# CS50P Issue - Little Professor "displays EEE when answer is incorrect" and "shows solution after 3 incorrect attempts"

Tags: python, cs50

I'm brand new to programming taking the CS50P course.  In the Little Professor assignment in Pset4 I am passing all the Check50 tests except the last two.  Running my code manually yields all the expected results per the problem sample video.  I am guessing that I have some type of operations order that gives the right result but check50 is not interpreting it as needed.  Here is my code:

```
import random


def main():
    score = 0
    level = get_level()

    for _ in range(10):
        x, y, correct_answer = generate_problem(level)
        user_attempts = 0

        while user_attempts < 3:
            print(f"{x} + {y} = ", end="")
            user_answer = get_user_input()

            if user_answer == correct_answer:
                score += 1
                break
            else:
                user_attempts += 1
                print("EEE")

        if user_attempts == 3:
            print(f"{x} + {y} = {correct_answer}")

    print(f"Score: {score}")


def generate_problem(prob_level):
    x = generate_integer(prob_level)
    y = generate_integer(prob_level)
    return x, y, x + y


def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            num_level = int(input("Level: "))
            if num_level in [1, 2, 3]:
                return int(num_level)
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            pass


def generate_integer(user_level):
    if user_level == 1:
        gen_int = random.randint(0, 9)
    elif user_level == 2:
        gen_int = random.randint(10, 99)
    else:
        gen_int = random.randint(100, 999)
    return gen_int


def get_user_input():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input())
            if user_input > 0:
                return user_input
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Errors reported by check50:
"Did not find "EEE" in "Level: 6 + 6 =..."" and "Did not find "12" in "Level: 6 + 6 =..."" .

When I run my code I properly see EEE three times, then the solution and then a new problem -

```
professor/ $ python professor.py
Level: 1
9 + 9 = 14
EEE
9 + 9 = 15
EEE
9 + 9 = 16
EEE
9 + 9 = 18
0 + 6 =
```

I have tried printing without f-strings, tried separating the printing of the problem and solution and even messed around with the for and while loops.

I realize my code may not be very efficient, but it generates the right solution.  Unfortunately, something is not formatted the way check50 expects it.  Maybe the order of my code is not right?  Any assistance is appreciated!!

Comment: It would help if you explained what the code is **supposed** to do.

Comment: if you click the link from Check50 to view the full report does it give any additional info?

Answer (score 0):

> something is not formatted the way check50 expects it

Bingo!

As per [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/) program structure is:

```
import random


def main():
    ...


def get_level():
    ...


def generate_integer(level):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I restructured my code, removing the functions not in the spec and everything works.  I appreciate the help.  I'll remember to stick to the spec in future problems.